# DNN 5 - Role expired, but user can still view pages

Tags: dotnetnuke, subscription, security-roles, dotnetnuke-5

I'm testing periodic fee subscriptions in DNN 5. I've set the renewal period on my custom role to 1 day.

After 1 day, the subscription shows as EXPIRED, but the user can still view all the pages accessible to that role.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, DNN checks the subscription expiration time on the WEB-SERVER, and "view permissions" on the DB-SERVER.

I changed the date on my web server so I didn't have to wait for 1 day for the role to expire. As soon as I changed the date on the DB server, I wasn't able to view the pages any more.